# Simple Subquery with OuterRef

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset, django-database

I am trying to make a very simple `Subquery` that uses `OuterRef` (not for practical purposes, but just to get it working), but I keep running into the same error.

`posts/models.py` code

```
from django.db import models

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`manage.py shell` code

```
>>> from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
>>> from posts.models import Tag, Post
>>> tag1 = Tag.objects.create(name='tag1')
>>> post1 = Post.objects.create(title='post1')
>>> post1.tags.add(tag1)
>>> Tag.objects.filter(post=post1.pk)
<QuerySet [<Tag: tag1>]>
>>> tags_list = Tag.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk'))
>>> Post.objects.annotate(count=Subquery(tags_list.count()))
```

The last two lines should give me number of tags for each Post object. And here I keep getting the same error:

```
ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

One of the problems with your example is that you cannot use `queryset.count()` as a subquery, because `.count()` tries to evaluate the queryset and return the count.

So one may think that the right approach would be to use `Count()` instead. Maybe something like this:

```
Post.objects.annotate(
    count=Count(Tag.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')))
)
```

This won't work for two reasons:

1. The `Tag` queryset selects all `Tag` fields, while `Count` can only count on one field. Thus: `Tag.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).only('pk')` is needed (to select counting on `tag.pk`).
2. `Count` itself is not a `Subquery` class, `Count` is an `Aggregate`. So the expression generated by `Count` is not recognized as a `Subquery` (`OuterRef` requires subquery), we can fix that by using `Subquery`.

Applying fixes for 1) and 2) would produce:

```
Post.objects.annotate(
    count=Count(Subquery(Tag.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).only('pk')))
)
```

**However**
if you inspect the query being produced:

```
SELECT 
    "tests_post"."id",
    "tests_post"."title",
    COUNT((SELECT U0."id" 
            FROM "tests_tag" U0 
            INNER JOIN "tests_post_tags" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."tag_id") 
            WHERE U1."post_id" = ("tests_post"."id"))
    ) AS "count" 
FROM "tests_post" 
GROUP BY 
    "tests_post"."id",
    "tests_post"."title"
```

you will notice a `GROUP BY` clause. This is because `COUNT` is an aggregate function. Right now it does not affect the result, but in some other cases it may. That's why the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression) suggest a different approach, where the aggregation is moved into the `subquery` via a specific combination of `values` + `annotate` + `values` :

```
Post.objects.annotate(
    count=Subquery(
        Tag.objects
            .filter(post=OuterRef('pk'))
            # The first .values call defines our GROUP BY clause
            # Its important to have a filtration on every field defined here
            # Otherwise you will have more than one group per row!!!
            # This will lead to subqueries to return more than one row!
            # But they are not allowed to do that!
            # In our example we group only by post
            # and we filter by post via OuterRef
            .values('post')
            # Here we say: count how many rows we have per group 
            .annotate(count=Count('pk'))
            # Here we say: return only the count
            .values('count')
    )
)
```

Finally this will produce:

```
SELECT 
    "tests_post"."id",
    "tests_post"."title",
    (SELECT COUNT(U0."id") AS "count" 
            FROM "tests_tag" U0 
            INNER JOIN "tests_post_tags" U1 ON (U0."id" = U1."tag_id") 
            WHERE U1."post_id" = ("tests_post"."id") 
            GROUP BY U1."post_id"
    ) AS "count" 
FROM "tests_post"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! However, when I add `pk__in=[1,2]` to the Tag filter, I get `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field`.

Comment: You can try to print the `queryset.query` and execute it in your `RDBMS` directly to see what you get in return. I guess that for some rows `Count` may return `NULL` instead of 0. You can try to confirm that by temporary exclude rows w/o count, i.e. `.filter(count__gte=1)`. However, `Subquery` accepts a second argument, which is `output_field` you can try set it to: `output_field=fields.IntegerField()`

Comment: @Todor Does not work for me. I get django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: I guess you have some filter missing, so you got more than one group per row which returns more than one count. You must have a filter on every field in your first `.values()` clause in the subquery.

Comment: having a default ordering set on Tag will make the GROUP BY include also the fields defined in the ordering in addition the ones in `values()`, which generates a `Subquery returns more than 1 row` error. fix by adding `).order_by('post').values('post')`

Answer (score 5):

The [django-sql-utils](https://github.com/martsberger/django-sql-utils) package makes this kind of subquery aggregation simple. Just `pip install django-sql-utils` and then:

```
from sql_util.utils import SubqueryCount
posts = Post.objects.annotate(
            tag_count=SubqueryCount('tag'))
```

The API for SubqueryCount is the same as Count, but it generates a subselect in the SQL instead of joining to the related table.