# Django: using an annotated aggregate in queryset update()

Tags: django, django-orm

I've run into an interesting situation in a new app I've added to an existing project. My goal is to (using a Celery task) update many rows at once with a value that includes annotated aggregated values from foreign keyed objects. Here are some example models that I've used in previous questions:

```
class Book(models.model):
    author = models.CharField()
    num_pages = models.IntegerField()
    num_chapters = models.IntegerField()

class UserBookRead(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    user_book_stats = models.ForeignKey(UserBookStats)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pages_read = models.IntegerField()

class UserBookStats(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    total_pages_read = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm attempting to:

1. Use the `post_save` signal from `Book` instances to update `pages_read` on related `UserBookRead` objects when a `Book` page count is updated.
2. At the end of the signal, launch a background Celery task to roll up the `pages_read` from each `UserBookRead` which was updated, and update the `total_pages_read` on each related `UserBookStats` (This is where the problem occurs)

I'm trying to be as lean as possible as far as number of queries- step 1 is complete and only requires a few queries for my actual use case, which seems acceptable for a signal handler, as long as those queries are optimized properly.

Step 2 is more involved, hence the delegation to a background task. I've managed to accomplish most of it in a fairly clean manner (well, for me at least).

The problem I run into is that when annotating the `UserBookStats` queryset with a `total_pages` aggregation (the `Sum()` of all `pages_read` for related `UserBookRead` objects), I can't follow that with a straight `update` of the queryset to set the `total_pages_read` field.

Here's the code (the `Book` instance is passed to the task as `book`):

```
# use the provided book instance to get the stats which need to be updated
book_read_objects= UserBookRead.objects.filter(book=book)
book_stat_objects = UserBookStats.objects.filter(id__in=book_read_objects.values_list('user_book_stats__id', flat=True).distinct())

# annotate top level stats objects with summed page count
book_stat_objects = book_stat_objects.annotate(total_pages=Sum(F('user_book_read__pages_read')))

# update the objects with that sum
book_stat_objects.update(total_pages_read=F('total_pages'))
```

On executing the last line, this error is thrown:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Aggregate functions are not allowed in this query
```

After some research, I found an existing Django ticket for this use case [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25643), on which the last comment mentions 2 new features in 1.11 that could make it possible.

Is there any known/accepted way to accomplish this use case, perhaps using `Subquery` or `OuterRef`? I haven't had any success trying to fold in the aggregation as a `Subquery`. The fallback here is:

```
for obj in book_stat_objects:
    obj.total_pages_read = obj.total_pages
    obj.save()
```

But with potentially tens of thousands of records in `book_stat_objects`, I'm really trying to avoid issuing an UPDATE for each one individually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to do this with `Subquery` and `OuterRef`, but had to take a different approach than I originally expected.

I was able to quickly get a `Subquery` working, however when I used it to annotate the parent query, I noticed that every annotated value was the *first* result of the subquery- this was when I realized I needed `OuterRef`, because the generated SQL wasn't restricting the subquery by anything in the parent query.

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression) part of the Django docs was super helpful, as was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770118/simple-subquery-with-outerref) StackOverflow question. What this process boils down to is that you have to use `Subquery` to create the aggregation, and `OuterRef` to ensure the subquery restricts aggregated rows by the parent query PK. At that point, you can annotate with the aggregated value and directly make use of it in a queryset `update()`.

As I mentioned in the question, the code examples are made up. I've tried to adapt them to my actual use case with my changes:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

# create the queryset to use as the subquery, restrict based on the `book_stat_objects` queryset
book_reads = UserBookRead.objects.filter(user_book_stat__in=book_stat_objects, user_book_stats=OuterRef('pk')).values('user_book_stats')
# annotate the future subquery with the aggregation of pages_read from each UserBookRead
total_pages = book_reads.annotate(total=Sum(F('pages_read')))
# annotate each stat object with the subquery total
book_stats = book_stats.annotate(total=Coalesce(Subquery(total_pages), 0))
# update each row with the new total pages count
book_stats.update(total_pages_read=F('total'))
```

It felt odd to create a queryset that cant be used on it's own (trying to evaluate `book_reads` will throw an error due to the inclusion of `OuterRef`), but once you examine the final SQL generated for `book_stats`, it makes sense.

**EDIT**

I ended up running into a bug with this code a week or two after figuring out this answer. It turned out to be due to a default `ordering` for the `UserBookRead` model. As the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) state, default `ordering` is incorporated into any aggregate `GROUP BY` clauses, so all of my aggregates were off. The solution to that is to clear the default ordering with a blank `order_by()` when creating the base subquery:

```
book_reads = UserBookRead.objects.filter(user_book_stat__in=book_stat_objects, user_book_stats=OuterRef('pk')).values('user_book_stats').order_by()
```